# Spring boot MYSQL capture data changes

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, stream, real-time

Can anyone help me how to capture changes on mysql database and send streams when data changes, my server is spring boot. Just i want the technology to use to handle this problem.

Comment: U can get change by kafka connector

Comment: do you have please a tutorial that helps me ?

Comment: Search confluent tutorial

Comment: ok, i found that we can use reactive crud repository and sending flux , do you have any idea about this ?